# How to capture and extract raw TCP packets including header

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, wireshark, tcpdump

I've implemented my TCP decoder (without IP, only TCP) and I want to test it.

**Q:** How can I get some raw TCP packets and it's headers? Is there a way to do so?

afaik, Wireshark allows you to save packets as `.pcap` files, but that adds me pcap-header, [and, possibly, ethernet and ip headers,] as an overhead, while i need raw data with TCP header only.

Comment: Since you are not specific on the tools you like to use or in what format you need to have the data I've marked it as duplicate of a question which asks how to extract TCP data from pcap using scapy. But even without scapy - pcap is an easy to parse [format](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat#file-format) and from each record you need only to subtract some fixed size header in order to get to the TCP header and payload. How much this header is depends on how the capture was done - but you can easily see the necessary offset when viewing the pcap in Wireshark.